# JavaScript .animate() not working on Iphone6

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs

I'm using react to animate a svg, as such:

```
handleImageLoadedLoadingScreen = (imgID, index) => {

const {
  originalImageStretch, 
  originalImageStretchArray, 
  viewportWidth
} = this.state;


let img = document.getElementById(imgID);

let originalImageHeight = img.getBoundingClientRect().width;
let loadingImgStrech = (viewportWidth/originalImageHeight)*1.02;

img.animate(
  [
    { transform: `rotateZ(90deg) translate(100%) scaleY(${loadingImgStrech})` },
    { transform: `rotateZ(90deg) translate(100%) scaleY(1)` },
  ], {
    duration: 1500,
    easing: "ease",
  }
);
```

}

Therefore:
1 - First, I calculate the SVG scale value
2 - Then, I apply the value to the animate() to do the transition

I cannot use CSS foe that (I suppose).

On Iphone 10 it's working but it does not work on Iphone6.

How can I make it work on this OS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix your @keyframes with -webkit-, and include the -webkit-prefixed animations and transitions there, instead of including them in your original

```
@keyframes:

@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-opacity: 0;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
```

becomes:

```
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        -webkit-opacity: 0;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }

@keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
```

and so on.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't geet it. Can you expand on what I need to do in dialogue with my React code? Thanks